# Parse Json and Print in ListView

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have a JSON Link here [JSON LINK](http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getLearningStandards)

How to parse this to get only One Tag of many its name but that tag must contains every id of its  node.. For example here One tag is Social Emotional that is more than 10 times having its different-2 is. but i want to select only its first tag that should contains its all id and description of its matching name. please help me . I am unable to parse it.. Screen Shot of JSON is here [SCREENSHOT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfYpJ.png)
 What I did is here..

```
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
     try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
            c = c.getJSONObject("LearningStandards");



            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            //String api = c.getString(TAG_API);




            // Adding value HashMap key => value


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            //map.put(TAG_API, api);

            oslist.add(map);
```

Comment: What value is in `TAG_OS ` variable ?

Comment: HI its mean = "LearningStandards"

Comment: ok then what problem u are getting because your parsing looking right?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K .. please help me sir.. I am in big trouble..:(

Comment: I dont know to to achieve such type requirement

Comment: There should be only one tag show from multiple duplicate tags Like Social Emotional.. but First Tag must contains itaa all data which have same name as Social Emotional

Comment: your parsing is right. tell us which problem u are getting. then we will try to help u

Comment: I am getting every node.. means if my JSON is conating 80 nodes then I am  able to get all 80 data.. but in 80 data, number of nodes are having same name.. please check my JSON sir, on JSON Viewer

Comment: I do not want to show every duplicate node in my listview... If there is 10 Social Emotional nodes in my json then i have to show only One Social Emotional but that tag must conatin every others Social Emotionals details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the code for you. you can fetch the value like this parsing steps.

```
String strJSONData = networkManager.doPost("http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getLearningStandards");

                    JSONArray objJson = new JSONArray(strJSONData);



                         System.out.println("AppUserLogin:"+objJson);
                        // Parsing json


                        if(arrJson.length()>0)
                        {
                        for (int i = 0; i < objJson.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject objprod = arrJson.getJSONObject(i);

                                HashMap<String, String> MaplistTemp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                MaplistTemp.put("replyCode",
                                        objprod.getString("replyCode"));

                                MaplistTemp.put("replyCode",
                                        objprod.getString("replyCode"));

                                JSONArray objproduct_var = new JSONArray(objprod.getString("LearningStandards"));

                                if ((objproduct_var.length()) > 0) {
                                    for (int k = 0; k < objproduct_var.length(); k++) {
                                        JSONObject objprodvar = objproduct_var
                                                .getJSONObject(k);



                                            MaplistTemp
                                                    .put("1",
                                                            objprodvar
                                                                    .getString("1"));
                                            MaplistTemp
                                                    .put("2",
                                                            objprodvar
                                                                    .getString("2"));
                                            MaplistTemp
                                                    .put("3",
                                                            objprodvar
                                                                    .getString("3"));
                                            MaplistTemp
                                            .put("4",
                                                    objprodvar
                                                            .getString("4"));

                                    }
                                }
                                // sub_categorys_details.add(sub_cat_det);

                        medpostList.add(MaplistTemp);// adding to final hashmap
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

your url have another array so do it again in "k" for loop and create another for loop j and get the value.
Note dopost method return type is String. if you have json object then use it accordingly.

Comment: Hi Avinash Thnxx bro... Let em ask you .. Where to put this code in my doItnBackgroun... ?

Comment: welcome bro. make vote up...you can put it into doInBackground() or also in  onPostExecute. if you can not handle this code inform me i will explain you or help you to understand it and write it.

Comment: HI bro.. thnxx fro your help.. actually I am new player in android so i need your guide line. Yesterday I made , now i ma able to get only one Node from multiple duplicated value but now again problem is here.. On selection on first node how to get all details...

Comment: welcome .okay no problem . actually i did not understand your new problem. just post the code and tell me what you want to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736719/parse-json-and-populate-its-value-into-listview-based-on-selection?noredirect=1#comment57220291_34736719

Comment: PLease plaese help me bro.. I am able to get my JSON data with one node from multiple same name in standard_title in JSON now but how to laod all data of select title ?

Comment: oh let me explain you what i have understand about your question. your list showing name . and you want to show ref_id and description value when user tap on showing title? right?

Comment: HI Pankaj please go through this Link.. Here is my actual code adn output you can see... 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736719/parse-json-and-populate-its-value-into-listview-based-on-selection?noredirect=1#comment57223132_34736719

Comment: Please click on it and see Pankaj's answer // There would be One output that I am getting... Now I want to print Only one Repeated Item As u r able to see in List That its conating number of TSG- Social Emotional more than one time.. I want to populate it One Time in my List and then when I press on it, it should return me all data of every its duplicated Social Emotional